# Why do higher level languages have neither xor nor nand short-circuit operators?

Tags: programming-languages, bitwise-operators

While many higher level languages have bitwise (exclusive or) and bitwise (exclusive and), for instance C, C++, Java, etc. I'm curious why the ( *vastly more useful* ) [logical short-circuit operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) don't have this functionality? Is it simply due to the capacity of being able to concatenate logic through use of "not"?

This question is mainly to do with the language design considerations....

Comment: You can't short circuit XOR.

Comment: @delnan Yes: hence the question

Comment: Short-circuits make sense in this context, if true andalso(orelse) thistrue.  XOR doesn't.

Comment: @Duncan I meant: The XOR operation can't possibly be implemented to short circuit; regardless of the value for the first operand, you always need the value of the second operand to determine the result. `0 AND x` is always 0, `1 OR x` is always 1, but both `0 XOR x` and `1 XOR x` can be both 0 or 1 depending on `x`.

Comment: @delnan you are only partially right. The name "xor" is ambiguous between two meanings: 1) oddity of number of true arguments and 2) if the only argument is true. The second meaning is rare but is used e.g. in Perl6 where `^^` is short-circuit multi-argument XOR. Properly we shall invent separate names for either variant, but regrettably legacy won't allow us to do this.

Comment: @Netch There's only ambiguity if you talk about an n-ary extension of the XOR operation, but the standard definition is a binary (2-ary) operation, and I see nothing in the question or comments indicating that OP is asking about a n-ary extension.

Comment: @delnan seems you didn't read IT books from early period (50-60s). The binary operation, yes, is unambiguous but its extensions aren't. And, yep, I don't see any limitation to binary operations in the question. Bitwise, but not binary.

Comment: @Netch No, I didn't (well, except the paper introducing hamming codes). But 50's and 60's books wouldn't help your case, focus and terminology change. Again, these extensions and their ambiguity is real but the default meaning of "XOR" is the 2-ary operation. Unless the speaker says "n-ary XOR" or something to that effect, I will not assume those extensions are of interest. Doubly so in the context of operators in programming languages, which are virtually always unary and binary, with longer expression just being nested application of the binary operation.

Comment: @delnan That's close to what I say. Most (well, likely 99.999%) treat XOR only in my 1st meaning, so I had been considering the 2nd meaning as totally historic - and I was highly confused when detected that Perl6 revived this obsolete meaning. Nevertheless, it shall be mentioned to describe the whole pictute.

Comment: @Netch: No matter how many arguments the XOR function takes, you always have to look at all of them to determine the result. So no short-circuiting.

Comment: @sth please consider the 2nd case carefully. If there are two arguments calculated to True, the result is False with any values of other, not calculated yet, arguments.

Comment: @Netch: Oh, after googling I understand that you wanted to say "2) if exactly one argument is true". The "if the only argument is true" was confusing because it sounds like there is one argument, and you check if it's true. Which wouldn't be a very interesting operator.

Comment: @sth Yep, it should be treated as function with many arguments. Thanks for editing, my English is still requiring some improving.

Comment: @sth: The parity operator needs all its arguments.  Not n-ary XOR.  With XOR, as soon as you find a second TRUE input, you're done, the output is false.

Comment: With a two-state Boolean type, xor depends upon both operands.  With SQL-style Boolean logic, `false AND X` yields false regardless of X, `true OR X` yields true regardless of X, and `null XOR X` yields null regardless of X, so all three operators could short-circuit.  Three-state logic probably isn't used enough to justify language support for short-circuiting XOR, but it would be semantically meaningful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Binary

#### Nand

Lets look at how NAND can be implemented with just AND or OR gates.

NAND becomes one of:

```
!(a && b)
!a || !b
```

Either of these can be seen as short circuiting.  The reason that NAND doesn't exist is that it is easily rewritten as `not(a and b)`

#### Xor

XOR, is at its heart, a parity checker.  To check the parity of two values, you need to test both values.  This is why it is fundamentally not able to short circuit it - you can't validate if the value is true or false until you test all the values.

Looking at how XOR is written with AND and OR gates:

```
(a || b) && !(a && b)
```

If `a` is true, the OR part of the xor can be short circuited, however it also means that the AND part *cannot* be short circuited.

### N-ary

N-ary operands take any number of inputs (compared to the binary ones that just take two).

#### Nand

The n-ary NAND is

```
!(a && b && c && d ... )
```

This again can be short circuited in that as soon as one of operands evaluates to false, the value of the NAND is true.

#### Xor

There are two different interpretations of the n-ary xor:

1. An odd number of true operand
2. One and only one true operand

The first one is in common usage (see [XOR at Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/XOR.html)):

> For multiple arguments, XOR is defined to be true if an odd number of its arguments are true, and false otherwise. This definition is quite common in computer science, where XOR is usually thought of as addition modulo 2.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate#More_than_two_inputs)

> Strict reading of the definition of exclusive or, or observation of the IEC rectangular symbol, raises the question of correct behaviour with additional inputs. If a logic gate were to accept three or more inputs and produce a true output if exactly one of those inputs were true, then it would in effect be a one-hot detector (and indeed this is the case for only two inputs). However, it is rarely implemented this way in practice.

The 'one hot' xor may be short circuited when evaluating the expression when finding the *second* true value.

Otherwise, again, the XOR is more commonly implemented as the "odd number of true values" which serves as a parity checker and requires the evaluation of all the operands to determine the truth of the expression as the last value evaluated can always change the truth of the expression.

Answer (score 13):

NAND is either `!a || !b` or `!(a && b)` both will be short circuited when `a` is false.

XOR can't be short circuited at all as [@delnan](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234210/why-do-higher-level-languages-have-neither-xor-nor-nand-short-circuit-operators/234211#comment468258_234210) explained

Answer (score 4):

Perl6 has got short-circuit XOR but its meaning of XOR is specific. I've repeat my comment jist here: there are two meanings of XOR:

1. if count of true arguments is odd
2. if only exactly one argument is true

Example for difference: `XOR (True, True, True)` gives `True` with the 1st meaning and `False` with the 2nd meaning. If Perl6 machine detects at least 2 arguments are true, it stops evaluation of rest because result is already determined as False.

But, for the 1st meaning (more traditional), one can't determine final result until all arguments are evaluated.

I think we should invent special clarification terms for these XOR variants, even if they won't be used outside of this discussion.

Comment: First one isn't XOR, it's parity function.  They get conflated because for 2 inputs they are the same.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree with your terms but the issue is that you should convince the majority.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is because the truth table for XOR doesn't have a single row of True's or False's.

- If the first argument to OR is True, then the answer is True, regardless of the second argument.
- If the first argument of AND is False, then the answer is False regardless of the second argument.
- BUT If the first argument of XOR is True, or False, it still needs the second argument because the truth value may "flip":

> True OR ? = True (always)
>
> False AND ? = False (always)
>
> True XOR ? = False or True
>
> False XOR ? = True or False